# Find URL of an open Chrome Tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently writing some code to allow me to interact with an actual Chrome tab.

The questions I have found here are all about first opening a tab via the webdriver and then interacting with that page. For example like:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open Chrome
driver.get(url)

# Get current url
print(driver.current_url)
# Click on a button
driver.find_element_by_xpath("example_xpath").click()
```

However, I want myself to open a page and then first my program should interact with that page and press certain buttons and such.

The reason is that when I open the page via my Python code that I have to log in automatically (which is not a problem) but afterwards I have to enter a security code after each opening of the page with Python. When I open the page myself, I am automatically logged in and no longer have to enter a security code.

If I want to try new code, I currently have to enter the security code every time I run the program, which takes forever.

Comment: The title of my question was not well chosen, because I don't want to find out only the URL, but interact with the complete page. Sorry for that :)

Comment: Which website are you trying to open? You can add ```cookie``` option to your ```webdriver```. Or you can automate the whole login procedure with ```Selenium```.

Comment: You can have a chrome profile or firefox profile, it won't ask you to login.

Comment: @Muhteva I want to open my email. I have already automate the whole login. My programm fills out my email adress and password and also sign in. But in the next step I have to write down a securiy code, which I get five minutes later at my smartphone. So every time I want to test my code, I have to wait five minutes until I get the security code. After I confirm the securiy code, the programms proceeds with further steps. My intenion is to open to open my email "manually" and after that to start my programm to interact with it